# Keycloak 11.0.0 generating token scope parameter invalid

Tags: oauth-2.0, jboss, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm in the process of updating Keycloak straight from version 6.0.1 to 11.0.0, the db migration was successful and was able to login into admin console, however the token generation seems to be broken, I'm sending below curl to generate token

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8480/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=testUser' \
--data-urlencode 'password=testPassword' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=testRole' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=testService' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=testServiceSecret'
```

On sending above request Keycloak complains of `Invalid Scopes: testRole`, however I've verified the role and user role mappings are in place and this used to work well with Keycloak 6.0.1.

Just on side note, our clients are Full scoped, so it something that is causing issue? Or something else have got changed or is there a way to ignore invalid scopes altogether while generating token?

Comment: Do you see `testRole` in `scopes_supported` section in `http://localhost:8480/auth/realms/test/kums/.well-known/openid-configuration`? BTW `scope` != `role`. For me it looks like you are mixing these two terms, especially when you are using full scope - it doesn't make sense to request role explicitly, when you receive all roles implicitly with enabled full scope.

Comment: @JanGaraj sorry for the  confusion, since we migrated from Keycloak 3.4( which has full scoped enabled) to Kecyloak  6 where all roles are implicitly returned if full scoped is true which worked fine for us (although we were getting all roles) now we are in the process of upgrading it to 11.0.0 and generating a scoped token complains if I provide my role as scoped parameter